Solving a drake::symbolic::expression for a graph of convex sets
I have a graph of convex sets where I am solving for the optimal path through multiple regions. I am working on improving the costs between each vertex (polygon-shaped regions). The cost to travel along the edge from vertex u to vertex v should be the distance from u to v multiplied by a scaling factor for traveling through that vectex. (The longer the edge travels through the vertex, the more effect that vertex will have on the cost)
i.e. cost_of_edge_from_u_to_v = distance_from_u_to_v * (factor_while_traveling_through_u * distance_from_start_point_to_end_of_u + factor_while_traveling_through_v * distance_from_start_of_v_to_end_point)
I am adding a cost to the edge as a drake::symbolic::expression. I would like to compute the intersection point of the path edge from u to v with one of the outer edges of the polygon, v. Using this intersection point, I will be able to compute the ratio of time in polygon u and in polygon v which will allow me to use the equation mentioned above to get a upper bound for the cost. Currently, I am running into issues of dividing by the determinate which can be zero at some points when solving for the intersection point.
An example of this could be a vehicle traveling from one region to another where the ground of the first region is muddy and the second is made of concrete. While the distance might be the same in region 1 and region 2 that the vehicle has to travel through, the cost will be much higher for traveling through the mud.
How should I use drake to create a continuous solution through convex sets while including specific edge costs (depending on the selected vertex)?

I think there are better ways to formulate this.
Let's assume, for the sake of discussion, that the polygons represent paths in ℜ³. Then it would be natural to create a GCS region for each of your regions in ℜ⁶ = ℜ³ x ℜ³. In words, each time you visit a vertex you pick 2 points in  the original space. Then you can add a vertex cost to each region that charges a region-specific-scalar times the (Euclidean?) distance between the two points. And you can add an edge constraint saying that the second point in u == the first point in v.
This is effectively the simplest version of the transcription that we used in the first GCS motion planning paper.

Thank you for your response! The example was very helpful. I have switched my solution to use the GcsTrajectoryOptimization class. I have my problem set up similarly to the book by having a source region (point), main region, and target region (point). How do I specify where the regions connect? I have added the edges between subgraphs correctly, but the solver is choosing a straight line between the source and target regions and ignoring the main region edges entirely. I believe this is because I am including some constraints on the source/target regions, but I am not sure what.

It's very hard for me to help without more details.

Understandable! Could you point me to where I could get access to the two points within each vertex? I would like to add a vertex-specific-cost and (as mentioned in the paper) a boundary-deterrant cost.

In GcsTrajectoryOptimization, when you call AddRegions, then you get back a Subgraph. You can loop through the vertices in the subgraph using subgraph.Vertices().  For each Vertex you can access the variables, and call AddCost.  E.g. v.AddCost(np.linalg.norm(v.x[:3] - v.x[-3:])).
(the ability to add l2 norm costs symbolically with linalg norm is a relatively recent feature, so you'll need an up to date version of Drake)

thanks for your help! One final question I had was about adding a cost for coming near an obstacle (only certain polygon boundaries). I am wanting to keep the plan a certain threshold/distance away from the obstacle. I am assuming I use the vertex->x() as the points to be selected. In my planner, x() has 16 values (x,y,z *5 + #ofpoints->value of 5 for 5 points). I would like to only add a cost if the point comes within say, 2, of the boundary, and otherwise do nothing. I have tried the if_then_else, addquadraticcost(). I do not know how drake handles the 16 values with added cost

If you just want to keep a threshold distance away (as a strict constraint), then you can just shrink the regions appropriately. Alternatively, in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2402.10312 section VIIB eq (18), we used a 1/x cost to encourage the solution to not get too close to the collisions. This can be transcribed into a convex cost (see example once that PR lands. Or you could add a nonconvex cost that would only be used during rounding.
